# updating text field display with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons and a text field. I want to update the display of the text field with the value of the buttons each time a button is pressed.

```js
function displayTextfield() { 
  var amount;
  amount = document.getElementById('btn').value;
  document.getElementById('other-amount') = amount;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn" onclick='displayTextfield()' role="button" value="A">A</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" id="btn" onclick='displayTextfield()' role="button" value="B">B</button>
<input type="text" class="form-control donation-amount-input" placeholder="Other Amount" id="other-amount" onclick='displayTextfield()'/>
```

When I run the click the button I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: You do not have a `#value` anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: And you got 2 buttons with the same id ("btn").

Comment: Change your third line inside the displayTextField function to document.getElementById('other-amount').value = amount;

Answer (score 1):

just add `id="value"` to `<input type="text" class="form...`

Answer (score 1):

hit run snippet below 
you can use a selector (I used the class btn) to target the buttons you are interested in.  then take advantage of $(this) to get the value of the clicked button

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('#other-amount').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="A">A</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" value="B">B</button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control donation-amount-input" placeholder="Other Amount" id="other-amount" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple solution.